# Firebase query returns empty when data is there

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this RTDB I am trying to search my users in, from a path called users -> UID -> and then the user key/values. One of them being "username". I want to append these to an array to return in my table view but no matter what I do, I keep getting back nothing.

```
var userRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    func queryText(_ text: String, inField child: String) {
        print(text)

        userRef.queryOrdered(byChild: child)
            .queryStarting(atValue: text)
            .queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { [weak self] (snapshot) in
                for case let item as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                    //Don't show the current user in search results
                    if self?.currentUser?.uid == item.key {
                        continue
                    }
                    
                    if var itemData = item.value as? [String:String] {
                        itemData["uid"] = item.key
                        self?.resultsArray.append(itemData)
                        print(self?.resultsArray)
                    }
                }
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Edit: I have verified I am able to print out the snapshot, I am just not getting the usernames added to my resultsArray. Anyone have a clue why?

```
    bio = " dfdf";
    displayname = chattest4;
    email = "test@test.com";
    "first_name" = chattest4;
    followers = 0;
    following = 0;
    "join_date" = "June 28, 2021";
    languages = English;
    "last_name" = test;
    location = "United States";
    profileImageURL = "hidjkfsf";
    username = chattest4;
```

Comment: EDIT: when I print the resultsArray, it is empty. Even if I am doing a valid search and my database is being reached.

Comment: Should have clarified, I am using Firebase.

Comment: WHICH Firebase service are you talking about?  Use the right tags.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to tag but mentioned in the post that this is Firebase Realtime Database.Added tag.

Comment: @ElTomato now that you know which Firebase service I was referring to, do you know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue. Some of the values in my database were not strings, but I had coded it to only look for Strings. Username was stored after these non-string values, so it never reached it. I just changed the array to [String:Any] and then it worked!

***if var itemData = item.value as? [String:Any]***